# How to display custom sorting option in backend

Tags: magento2.3.3

Hi i have recently created most viewed product sorting option for my store and its working fine but i want to add that option to be enable or disable from the backend here in sorting option where position, price and name is visible

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add InstallData.php for add attribute in category

**VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup**

***InstallData.php***

```
<?php
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{


    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1', '<=')) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                'is_enable_sorting',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Recently Created Most Viewed Product Sorting',
                    'input' => 'Boolean',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',

                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

overrite default category form and add our attribute

**VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

***category_form.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="display_settings">
        <field name="is_enable_sorting">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Recently Created Most Viewed Product Sorting</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                        <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                        </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now you can Filter category collection by this attribute

```
 protected $_categoryFactory;

 public function __construct(
       ..........................................
       ..........................................
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
    ) {
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
        $this->_categoryFactory = $collecionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
    }
    public function getSortingEnableCategory()
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $category->addAttributeToFilter('is_enable_sorting', 1);
        $category->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        return $category;
    }
```

call in phtml file

```
$category = $block->getSortingEnableCategory();
```

[image]

***I hope this Helps you.***